# Group by with further grouping

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sample data:

```
    ID | SectionID | LocID

    1      32        12
    1      32        2
    1      32        2
    1      34        3
    1      34        4
    2      36        8
    2      36        9
    2      37        8
    2      37        9
    2      37        4
```

The output should be grouped by ID. The Count LocID field should show the
number of DISTINCT LocIDs per sectionID totaled together.

For ID of 1, we have 2 distinct LocID for SectionID 32 and 2 for SectionID 34. Totaled equals 4

For ID of 2, we have 2 distinct LocID for SectionID 36 and 3 for sectionID  37. Total equals 5

Result:

```
    ID  Count 
    1   4
    2   5
```

I did a group by ID but not sure how to do further grouping based on what I need. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Is the thing you wrote in the Result box the output you want?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes that is the result. I am looking for distinct LocID counts per SectionID totaled together grouped by ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested group by, such as

```
SELECT ID, SUM([Count])
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SectionID, COUNT(DISTINCT LocID) AS [Count]
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY ID, SectionID
) Q
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way, I think, is to group by your ID and do some kind of count distinct on a concatenation of SectionID and LocID.  If these are character data, you can get away with just concatenating with some kind of delimiter.  If their numeric, you can do something like the example below, or convert them to strings and concat with a delimiter.

```
-------------------------
-- set up sample data
-------------------------

declare @datatable as table(ID int, SectionID int, LocID int)
insert into @datatable(ID, SectionID, LocID) VALUES
    (1,32,12    ),
    (1,32,2 ),
    (1,32,2 ),
    (1,34,3 ),
    (1,34,4 ),
    (2,36,8 ),
    (2,36,9 ),
    (2,37,8 ),
    (2,37,9 ),
    (2,37,4     )

-------------------------
-- The query
-------------------------

SELECT
     ID 
     ,COUNT (DISTINCT SectionID * 10000 + LocID)
FROM
    @datatable
GROUP BY ID
```

Gives the result:

```
(10 row(s) affected)
ID          
----------- -----------
1           4
2           5

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: That is indeed an interesting solution. I never would have thought of doing that. According to the statistics of my very limited dataset, of 10000 rows, they are literally neck in neck on performance.

Answer (score 0):

A down and dirty way is to just nest your groupings.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
 ID INT,
 SectionID INT,
 LocID INT 
);

INSERT INTO @t
  (
    ID
   ,SectionID
   ,LocID
  )
VALUES
  ( 1,32,12),
  ( 1,32,2),
  ( 1,32,2),
  ( 1,34,3),
  ( 1,34,4),
  ( 2,36,8),
  ( 2,36,9),
  ( 2,37,8),
  ( 2,37,9),
  ( 2,37,4) 

SELECT
  d.ID
 ,SUM(d.LocIDs) AS LocIDCnt
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ID
     ,SectionID
     ,COUNT(DISTINCT LocID) AS LocIDs
    FROM
      @t
    GROUP BY
      ID
     ,SectionID
  ) AS d
GROUP BY
  d.ID;
```

Result set:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Count |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     4 |
|  2 |     5 |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
select ID, COUNT(*) as SecLocCount
from (
    select distinct ID, SectionID, LocID from [MyTable]
) AS distinctRows
group by ID
```